# Getting first data from an dataset in API

Tags: jquery, api

So I am trying to get the first item this API delivers in that class to get the latest Stoh values for a currency. However I can't get that first item without using the exact date and time the latest data was released. 
How would I get the first item? I tried storing it in a variable using a for loop couldn't figure that out.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var stohas =
    "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=STOCH&symbol=EURUSD&interval=5min&slowkmatype=1&slowdmatype=1&apikey=APIKEY123456";
  $.getJSON(stohas, function(edata) {
    // console.log(edata["Technical Analysis: STOCH"]["2017-11-22 18:15"] );

    //i wanna get that console item from api without using the exact date. because i won't know the date each time the function is called and i dont wan use a static date.
    var stoh = edata["Technical Analysis: STOCH"];
    console.log(stoh["2017-11-22 18:15"]);
  });
});
```

```html
{
"Meta Data": {
"1: Symbol": "EURUSD",
"2: Indicator": "Stochastic (STOCH)",
"3: Last Refreshed": "2017-11-22 18:15:00",
"4: Interval": "15min",
"5.1: FastK Period": 5,
"5.2: SlowK Period": 3,
"5.3: SlowK MA Type": 1,
"5.4: SlowD Period": 3,
"5.5: SlowD MA Type": 1,
"6: Time Zone": "US/Eastern Time"
},
"Technical Analysis: STOCH": {
"2017-11-22 18:15": {
"SlowD": "23.8667",
"SlowK": "23.4675"
},
"2017-11-22 18:00": {
"SlowD": "24.2660",
"SlowK": "13.6016"
},

},
}
```

Comment: {
"Meta Data": {
"1: Symbol": "EURUSD",
"2: Indicator": "Stochastic (STOCH)",
"3: Last Refreshed": "2017-11-22 18:15:00",
"4: Interval": "15min",
"5.1: FastK Period": 5,
"5.2: SlowK Period": 3,
"5.3: SlowK MA Type": 1,
"5.4: SlowD Period": 3,
"5.5: SlowD MA Type": 1,
"6: Time Zone": "US/Eastern Time"
},
"Technical Analysis: STOCH": {
"2017-11-22 18:15": {
"SlowD": "23.8667",
"SlowK": "23.4675"
},
"2017-11-22 18:00": {
"SlowD": "24.2660",
"SlowK": "13.6016"
},

},
}

Comment: I know i am as exasperated as you are, sorry first time using the site to ask qs's... gna learn the proper way to post code asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```
for(var key in edata["Technical Analysis: STOCH"]) break;
edata["Technical Analysis: STOCH"][key];
```

Here `for loop` will store the 1st date into the Key and immediately break it so you will have the exact data of the 1st item into the key.

Later you can access that data by using that key as shown above.

Comment: That worked, it gets the first item and posts it! Thanks